# Update script's file-name after saving

Tags: scripting

Is there a way to force blender to update the script's filename in the little name-field at the top after I save it under a different name? The filename remains the same after saving and its quite confusing. Or am I missing a setting somewhere?

[image]

Comment: One way is to change the "Text" name to what you want the file name to be and then Alt->S save the file.

Comment: Saving through the drop down menu or pressing ALT+S will not alter the name in the top of the screen, or maybe you are talking about something different?

Answer (score 1):

For clarity I'll post this as an answer.

Enter the file name you want in the box at the top of the screen:

[image]

[image]

Then save the file. This is the bottom of the file save dialog:

[image]

I created a new Text file, but you can see that the saved filed is listed with the name it was saved with:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Hmmm, a little bit cumbersome way to save. Also this works only for new files. If you open a file, then edit the name in the box and try to save it still has the old name. Either way thank you.

Comment: There may be a much better way of doing this. Unfortunately, this is what I have. What you can do in the case of editing the name in the box of an opened file is to use the Save As option and change the file name in the Save As dialog to match what you entered in the box.